# How to convert HttpEntity into JSON?

Tags: android, json, web-services

I want to retrieve JSON from a web-service and parse it then.
Am I on the right way?

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
           // parsing JSON
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to convert `HttpEntity` into a JSONObject.

This is my JSON (extract):

```
{
    "names": [
        {
            "name": "Zachary"
        },
        {
            "name": "Wyatt"
        },
        {
            "name": "William"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can convert string to json as:

```
try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
           String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(entity); 
           // parsing JSON
           JSONObject result = new JSONObject(retSrc); //Convert String to JSON Object

             JSONArray tokenList = result.getJSONArray("names");
             JSONObject oj = tokenList.getJSONObject(0);
             String token = oj.getString("name"); 
        }
}
 catch (Exception e) {
  }
```

Comment: It says `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String`, so I changed it to `String token = (String) result.get("token");`. But unfortunately I receive nothing when I try `Log.d("token", token);`, altough the entity is `!=null` and I have valid JSON.

Comment: ok then can u post me your json feed link bez it's possible your json object contain another JsonArray then you need use JSONArray first and then extract value from array

Comment: if it contain array then add JSONArray tokenList = result.getJSONArray("result");JSONObject oj = tokenList.getJSONObject(0);String token = oj.getString("token");

Comment: Where does the `nameList` come from?

Comment: Where is EntityUtils from?\

Comment: for the EntityUtils, import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

Comment: EntityUtils.toString  MY SAVIOR! NICE FIND!

Answer (score 1):

Using gson and EntityUtils:

```
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

try {
    if (responseEntity != null) {
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
        JsonObject jsonResp = new Gson().fromJson(responseString, JsonObject.class); // String to JSONObject

    if (jsonResp.has("property"))
        System.out.println(jsonResp.get("property").toString().replace("\"", ""))); // toString returns quoted values!

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the entity.getContent() to get the InputStream and convert it to String.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public String getMyFeed(){
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpclien.execute(httpget);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    HttpInputStream content = entity.getContent();

    StatusLine sl = response.getStatusLine();
    int statCode = sl.getStatusCode()

   if (statCode ==200){

    // process it

}

}


String readFeed  = getMyFeed();
JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(readFeed);

for(int i=0 ; i<jArr.length ; i++)
JSONObject jObj = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void responce() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            org.apache.http.client.HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.example.com/api/authenticate");
    
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserName", "anything"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "usepassworld"));
            
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
    
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    
            if (entity != null){
               String string_1 = EntityUtils.toString(entity); 
               System.out.println("the token we are generated is -->"+ string_1);   
                }
            }           
    }
```