# How to write php code to input jsonstring and insert to sql server

Tags: php, android, json

i am trying to OUTPUT a Json String from the phone and to get it uploaded to the sql server i have. I Do not know how to get the output Json and write the php code... i tried many methods but couldnt find a solution.

```
public void post(String string) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://www.hopscriber.com/xoxoxox/testphp.php");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myJson", string));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent())
                    .toString();
            Log.w("SENCIDE", str);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "notwork", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    private Object inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Read response until the end
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return full string
        return total;
    }
```

it outputs a json string as

```
[myJson=[{"name":"FriendTracker","user":"amjgp000000000000000","pack":"org.siislab.tutorial.friendtracker","perm":"org.siislab.tutorial.permission.READ_FRIENDS","level":"Normal"},{"name":"FriendTracker","user":"amjgp000000000000000","pack":"org.siislab.tutorial.friendtracker","perm":"org.siislab.tutorial.permission.WRITE_FRIENDS","level":"Normal"},{"name":"FriendTracker","user":"amjgp000000000000000","pack":"org.siislab.tutorial.friendtracker","perm":"org.siislab.tutorial.permission.FRIEND_SERVICE","level":"Normal"},{"name":"FriendTracker","user":"amjgp000000000000000","pack":"org.siislab.tutorial.friendtracker","perm":"org.siislab.tutorial.permission.FRIEND_NEAR","level":"Dangerous"},{"name":"FriendTracker","user":"amjgp000000000000000","pack":"org.siislab.tutorial.friendtracker","perm":"org.siislab.tutorial.permission.BROADCAST_FRIEND_NEAR","level":"Normal"},{"name":"FriendTracker","user":"amjgp000000000000000","pack":"org.siislab.tutorial.friendtracker","perm":"android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED","level":"Normal"},{"name":"FriendTracker","user":"amjgp000000000000000","pack":"org.siislab.tutorial.friendtracker","perm":"android.permission.READ_CONTACTS","level":"Dangerous"},{"name":"FriendTracker","user":"amjgp000000000000000","pack":"org.siislab.tutorial.friendtracker","perm":"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION","level":"Dangerous"},{"name":"FriendTracker","user":"amjgp000000000000000","pack":"org.siislab.tutorial.friendtracker","perm":"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE","level":"Dangerous"},{"name":"FriendTracker","user":"amjgp000000000000000","pack":"org.siislab.tutorial.friendtracker","perm":"android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE","level":"Dangerous"},{"name":"Tesing","user":"amjgp000000000000000","pack":"com.example.tesing","perm":"null","level":"null"},{"name":"Action Bar","user":"amjgp000000000000000","pack":"name.brucephillips.actionbarexample","perm":"null","level":"null"},.......
```

My Php which i tried

```
include("config.php");
$link = connect_db();

$jsonString=$_POST['myJson'];

$root = json_decode($jsonString, true);

foreach ($root as $item)
{
$user=$item['user'];
$name=$item['name'];
$pack=$item['pack'];
$perm=$item['perm'];
$level=$item['level'];

$sql ="INSERT INTO `Survey_Application_Data`(`User`, `Name`, `package`, `manifest_permission`, `protection_level`) VALUES ('$user','$name','$pack', '$perm','$level')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($result){

    echo "True";
}
else{
    echo "False";
}

}


?>
```

Comment: What's your question? How to handle the POST in php and write it to a database?

Comment: Yes..... need to handle the Json String post and write a php to write it to the DB

Comment: Show us what you've done so far and where your problem is. This isn't the place to ask for a complete solution. PHP supports JSON and SQL, so putting those two pieces together isn't terribly difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804466/how-to-convert-httpentity-into-json) To decode/phrase the JSON response from the PHP server .
You can simply convert a response to a string by

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Then turn it into a JSON Object and use `getString` to assign it to a new `String`

```
JSONObject jsonResponseText = new JSONObject(responseText);
String name = jsonResponseText.getString("name");//To get the "name"
String user = jsonResponseText.getString("user");//To get the "user"
//etc...
```

*EDITED*
If you are only passing one set of data to the PHP Server at a time, just add each params in the `nameValuePairs`

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "FriendTracker"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "amjgp000000000000000"));
//etc ...
//and execute the httppost
```

and then in your php code you can simply use:

```
$name= $_POST["name"];
$user = $_POST["user"];
//etc ...
```