# org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1

Tags: java, json

I tried searching for this error. There are many results on google for this search but nothing proved useful to me. 
This is my web service method

```
@GET
@Path("/values")
public String test() {

    return "{\"x\":5,\"y\":6}";

}
```

This is my client code

```
public class Check {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String url = "http://localhost:8181/math/webapi/values";
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        String value = response.toString();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(value);
        int i = json.getInt("x");
        System.out.println(i);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

The above code is a starter code and it is for learning how to use it. If this is solved, I have to apply the knowledge in another application. The client side code, I want to use the logic in android.

**EDIT**

```
public class Check {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String url = "http://localhost:8181/math/webapi/values";
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        InputStream value = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(value));
        String jsonValue = br.readLine();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonValue);
        int i = json.getInt("x");
        System.out.println(i);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Likely your response contains a header? Try printing the value of `value`. **Edit** likely `response.toString` is not overridden from `Object#toString` and you're getting the `ClassName@hashCode` idiom.

Comment: What if you print `value`?

Comment: Are you sure the HTTP API you're using is synchronous? Are you sure that `HttpResponse#toString` returns the response rather than the generic `toString`?

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger and examine `value`. That's the only rational way to approach figuring this out. If you don't have a debugger, stop what you're doing and get one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get an http response body as a string in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769717/how-can-i-get-an-http-response-body-as-a-string-in-java)

Comment: You need to obtain the content of the response and feed it into the JSON parser: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10804506/3215527

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks thomas for the suggestion. I'll debug it.

Comment: @Thomas as I said, it is not the real application. I'm doing it to learn. I have to apply it in another application.

Comment: @Mena Thanks for the help offered Mena. I'm not getting how can I override toString() using that response in client program. And what you said is right. I got the hashcode value when I did this `System.out.println(response);`. Can you help me further?

Comment: @Krishna you may want to take a look at the API you're using (Apache?) and get a tutorial on how to parse the actualn response text, excluding headers. Clearly invoking `toString` won't work there. Overriding `toString` is likely not an option for you as this is not code you're owning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Use IOUtils as mentioned. it will work.

```
public class Check {
public static void main(String[] args){
String url = "http://localhost:8181/math/webapi/values";
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    InputStream value = response.getEntity().getContent();
    String jsonValue = IOUtils.toString(value);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonValue);
    int i = json.getInt("x");
    System.out.println(i);
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fairly certain `response.toString` doesn't do what you think it does, as it's not [listed in the documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html).

I believe you need to use [`response.getEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getEntity()), and then [`entity.getContent`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent()), which gives you an `InputStream` to read the content from. Then pass that stream into your parser.

Comment: Edited the question with modified code. Still same error using that code. Thanks for the immediate response. But can you help me further.