# Can not find the Json object (Using org.json)

Tags: java, json, azure-cognitive-services

[Microsoft Academic](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Academic-Knowledge-API/documentation/EvaluateMethod) provided an API to get some general information from Microsoft academic. The response type is a Json Object. Using [org.Json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160810) and following code, I have tried to read the response object but I have failed (need to download [these](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) jars + common-logging and common-codec) :

```
    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?");

    builder.setParameter("expr", "Composite(AA.AuN=='jaime teevan')");
    builder.setParameter("count", "100");
    builder.setParameter("attributes", "Ti,CC");

     URI uri = builder.build();
     HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);

    request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "Your-Key");


        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


        if (entity != null) {

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(entity);


            JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("entities");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){

            String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("Ti");
                System.out.println(post_id);

            }    

            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        }
```

Which returns the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["entities"] not found.
at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:471)
at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:618)
```

How to fix this?

**EDIT** 
Although it is easy to see an example of the response from the link I provided at the beginning of my question (Microsoft Academic), but for ease of readers I show it in here:

```
    {
  "expr": "Composite(AA.AuN=='jaime teevan')",
  "entities": 
  [
    {
      "logprob": -15.08,
      "Ti": "personalizing search via automated analysis of interests and activities",

      "CC": 372,
    },
    {
      "logprob": -15.389,
      "Ti": "the perfect search engine is not enough a study of orienteering behavior in directed search",
      "CC": 237,


    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How does the response look like? Did you maybe get an error message back? From the error message you can see that there is no `entities` property in the returned object.

Comment: Please click on the first word in my question (Microsoft Academic) to see an example of the response. surely, when I use`System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));` I can see the whole response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem to me is you are not converting your response to `string` , you need to convert your response to `string` before passing it to `JSONObject`

```
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        entity.writeTo(os);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    }
    String contentString = new String(os.toByteArray());
```

or other way is

```
InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
String contentString  = sb.toString(); //  you can pass sb.toString() directly to jsonobject as well
```

and now pass `contentString` to `JSONObject`

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(contentString);
 JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("entities");
```

Update : your can also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804466/how-to-convert-httpentity-into-json) which is also suggested by @Ömer Fadıl Usta 
but i would strongly recommend to use `HttpURLConnection` for security and performance

Comment: put your updated clause in your question with new code with error , i hope you are not doing this twice `entity.getContent();` in your code

Comment: I found out my mistake and that is why i deleted my comment. silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass string JsonData to JSONObject :

```
if (entity != null) {
    String jsonData = EntityUtils.toString(entity); 
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    ........
    .....
}
```

Comment: @PavneetSingh are you sure ? Because I have tried on my native java platform (don't have any android sdks are installed ) and EntityUtils from org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

Comment: i forgot i don't have apache on my new java8  setup , i was going to give this too but didn't  cuz tried on java8  :P:P

Comment: @PavneetSingh without apache http client jars how can you use HttpClient ?

Comment: cuz i knew the answer but i didn't test it and i have solved thousands of HttpClient issue while providing debugging services and it's a deprecated API in android from a long time so don't use it anymore and plus you could have suggested your answer as edit to mine instead of after reading solution and posting