# Fetch JSON property from HttpResponse object in Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, json, http, servlets, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using Apache HttpClient 4.2 and just need to fetch the `title` property from the JSON response below.

Would I need to use the EntityUtils.toString() method for this?

**Code**

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(MAILCHIMP_API_URL);

postRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
postRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + MAILCHIMP_API_KEY_BASE64);

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF8");
postRequest.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

// Closes the connection
EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
```

**JSON Response**

```
{
  "type": "http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
  "title": "Member Exists",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "user@domain.com is already a list member. Use PUT to insert or update list members.",
  "instance": ""
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804466/how-to-convert-httpentity-into-json) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (jackson2 lib):

```
TypeReference<Map> mapType = new TypeReference<Map>() {};
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, String> responseJson = 
mapper.readValue(response.readEntity(String.class), mapType);
String typeValue = responseJson.get("type");
```

Probably you may want to create only one instance of mapper and mapType.
But, I would prefer to create a java class which will represent your json and use

```
mapper.readValue(response.readEntity(String.class), YourType.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http-request built on apache http api. Documentation [here](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request/).

```
private static final HttpRequest<Map<String, Object>> HTTP_REQUEST =
    HttpRequestBuilder.createPost(MAILCHIMP_API_URL, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
    })
    .addContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + MAILCHIMP_API_KEY_BASE64)
    .build();
public void method() {
    String title = HTTP_REQUEST.executeWithBody(json.toString()).get().get("title");
}
```